# how to inject the route into camel FileFilter

Tags: spring, apache-camel

Is there a way to inject the route into camel FileFilter ?
I have this camel route :

```
<route id="mislaka-bituch">
                    <from
                           uri="ftp://{{mislaka_bituch_in_path}}?filter=#fileFilter&amp;readLock=none&amp;delete=true&amp;moveFailed=.error&amp;sortBy=file:modified" />
                    <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" />
                    <to uri="bean:redirectService?method=analyzeMislaka" />
                    <toD uri="ftp://${exchangeProperty[targetPath]}" />
             </route>
```

And in my FileFilter I have the method :

```
public boolean accept(GenericFile<T> file)
```

But how do i get the route info (name for example) in this class ?

Comment: I think you can't, but can use other types of filters (e.g. bean based `filter().method(SomeFilter.class, "isAccept").`).

Comment: Check this thread where you can find a workaround: http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/How-to-get-RouteId-in-a-GenericFileFilter-td5723631.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes as said in the comments, you cannot get the id of the route etc, in the `FileFilter` method, you can only get file information from the `GenericFile`.

Comment: thank you . I found that I only need to use the autoStart option on the route and this is enough